# nltk.download() failed with the http error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I run the `nltk.download()` to download the data, but the process failed with the following error message. What may be the reasons? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: care to provide more background? e.g. which kind of data, where does it come from?

Comment: I was just following the link of  http://www.nltk.org/data.html

Comment: And your operating system is?..

Comment: Also, are you behind a firewall? Perhaps you should look at "Installing via a proxy web server" section on the same page.